# Динамический запрос в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь реализовать в PostgreSql функциональность аналогичную ф-ии sp_executesql из MS Sql. Характерный запрос в MS Sql:

```
declare @field varchar(10) = 'cnt'
declare @table varchar(10) = 'nr.Cnt'
declare @sql nvarchar(100) = 'select top 1 ' + @field + ' from ' + @table
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Суть в том, что требуется, чтобы в качестве параметров @field и @table можно было подставлять любые приемлемые в текущей БД значения.

Погуглил, подходящего решения для PostgeSql не нахожу, может кто подскажет?

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема, параметры в динамические запросы любые передаются. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html

Comment: Проблема в том, что в качестве параметра динамического запроса не может быть передан объект БД. Попробуйте сделать с помощью динамического запроса аналог того, что я привел в качестве примера

Comment: так его и не надо передавать как параметр, подставляете его в строку точно так же как делали в ms sql

Comment: Спасибо, чет я протупил, мог бы и сам сообразить

Comment: В продолжение темы: